# Issue while reading a property file in Perl

Tags: perl

I want to read a property file using perl.
My property file abc.properties is of the form :

```
jdk=Path1:Path2:PathN
soa=Path1:Path2:PathN
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my %o;
open my $in, "abc.properties" or die $!;
while(<$in>) {
   $o{$1}=$2 while m/(\S+)=(\S+)/g;
}
close $in;

for (keys %o) {
     my @value_array = @{$o{$_}};
     print "Key is $_ and value is @values\n";
}
```

The output is : 
Key is jdk and value is
Key is soa and value is

I am unable to read the value corresponding to the key.My aim is to read the value and then split it on :

Being new to perl,any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: Is there only one value per key? Also, `use strict; use warnings;` is missing.

Comment: yes,for each key there is only one value containing multiple colons :

Comment: Always `use strict`. Always `use warnings`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to create an array of values if you are expecting and storing only a single value per key.

```
for (keys %o) {
     print "Key is $_ and value is $o{$_}\n";
}
```

Also, `if` should be used instead of `while` on the line that matches the regular expression. How can a line match several times?

Adding `use strict; use warnings;` would inform you about some mistakes you made (i.e. confusing @value_array and @values).